# django admin site editing

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

For some reason I need to access current object while editing module in admin. How can I do so.

Let's see example:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ISBN = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ManyToManyField(Publisher)
```

In admin form, I have autocomplete field for author and publisher. For that I have built custom widget. My admin form looks like:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=AutoCompleteWidget('author'), help_text="Please type author name")
    publisher = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=AutoCompleteWidget('publisher'), help_text="Please type publisher name")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['initial'] = {'publihser': {author_list}, 'author' : {publisher_list}}

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

As you see, the form is completely different so as default behavior will be changed. While editing book from admin, I would like get all associated publisher and author for author_list and publisher_list. I can set initial values in admin form. But I need to know current book and it's id to fetch associated publisher and author. How to get current book object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how you've set up your models. If `Package`s have an `author` and `publisher` and a book has `Package`s, then you should simply have a field on `Book` like:

```
packages = models.ManyToManyField(Package)
```

*Not* two `ManyToManyField`s both pointing to `Package` named `author` and `publisher`. For one, I'm not even sure how you got this code to run in the first place, as Django would try to create two identically named join tables for the relationships (Book->Package, the actual attribute name doesn't matter in this context).

Comment: ...thanks and sorry. I have typo mistake in my question that because I copied code. Now I have edited.